# How to enable jumbo frame and large TCP on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, tcp, jumboframes

I needed to enable the jumbo frame 9000 in network setting, and I have already done that.

I still need to enable large TCP on Windows Server 2008, but how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

In the driver settings.

Right-click->Properties on the NIC the click Configure... in the Advance tab.